# Parse: Cannot receive notifications from Console

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm struggling with getting push notifications to work on iOS using the parse console. I'm not getting anything to my phone.

When I'm sending from the console it says "This will be sent to 2 devices".

```
TARGETING
deviceType is "ios"
SENDING TIME
January 20th, 2015 at 6:27 PM
EXPIRATION
None
FULL TARGET
{ "deviceType": "ios" }
FULL DATA
{ "alert": "Hello", "sound": "default" }
```

I've checked, rechecked and retried:

- https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications
- https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/iOS
- [developer.apple.com - ConfiguringPushNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html)
- Only Ascii in Parse app name
- Tried development and production certificates aswell as ad-hoc installed via iTunes.
- App Bundle identifier is the same across parse, xcode, and profiles.
- Regenerating certificates, profiles with a different bundle identifier.
- Refreshing account in Xcode, restarting, and clean build.
- Using the right Provisioning Profile
- Tried sending with Parse-settings on "Released in Production" on and off having both certificates uploaded.
- The iOS codes is taken from parse examples and in _Installations I get a deviceToken.

With [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) I'm able to send pushes to the App using the same certificate(Sandbox) I've uploaded. This can further exclude the certificate as the error source.

Implemented methods as in Parse documentation:

AppDeligate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Sending a notification from Parse should be relatively simple. Did you upload your certificate and the Parse said that it's valid?

Comment: Where are you setting your device token?

Comment: I get no errors what so ever concerning certificates. The deviceToken is received and saved into _Installations. That code is just copy-paste from their tutorial.

Comment: So, did you try to create a user in the  default "_User" table? And try to manually uploaded the token? And use the dashboard to push manually also. I encountered the same problem before. It turned out that I just made small mistake. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LucasHuang Yes, but when I'm using the console I'm avoiding those traps and going straight on _Installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `_Installation` `pushType` was not set to the proper value `apns` as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Using the console you can explicitly implore the payload with custom attributes using JSON. First ensure it's correctly syntaxed. Looking at [Parse's Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/iOS) you can see what's relevant to your targeted device. If your strictly sending a push from the website console than you can send a push in segments, targeting iOS, when building your push, and then in "Write Your Message" switch the payload type to json as opposed to plain text and include the following or something similar, you don't have to include iOS in the payload when sending from the console :

```
{ "aps": 
    { "alert": “New post published!", 
      "badge": 1, 
      "sound": "ding.wav" 
    }, 
"acme1": "bar", "acme2": 42 
}
```

*note :* you might have to include `content-available` pending compatibility.

You can review the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15) for reference to 'bar' and '42'.

It looks like your set up is good to go based off the information you provided so hopefully it's just a quick syntax fix. If it states that it's sending to 2 devices, then you clearly have done the set-up justice, that process is complete due to the fact that the backend is aware those devices have successfully agreed to push notifications.

Comment: Got nothing. :( I'm also trying with Pusher.app using the same deviceToken and APN-certificate as on Parse, then I get the push. I get pushes to Android using the console however.

Comment: @Gustav There should be no variance, Pusher.app uses the same resources in the app bundle that Parse uses. can you update your question with all the methods implemented relating to Parse in your AppDelegate

Comment: The problem is that Parse never sends a Push, not that I can't receive them on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement this delegate method and show Dictionary Data:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;

You will see all information ind dictionary

Comment: That is not the problem. Pushes are never sent to begin with.